# Вылетает kivy, не успев запуститься. На ПК

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, popup

Здравстуйте! Возникла такая проблема. Заметил, что мои kivy приложения попросту вылетают, неуспев запуститься. Решил написать простенький код, проверить, будет ли он работать, так он тоже не работает, приложение kivy попросту вылетает.

Код:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text="hhh")

MainApp().run()
```

[image: Kivy crushing(]

P.S. Да, я в командной строке сначала сглупил, но потом исправил и, как видите, всё равно не работает (

### Заранее благодарю!

---

- Windows 10 корпоративная;
- Python 3.6.3
- Kivy 1.11.1

---

Всем добра-бобра!

Comment: На скриншоте, на заднем фоне есть текст ошибки, где AttributeError,. наверное, там и причина проблемы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### РЕШЕНО!

Я не знаю, в чём была проблема, я просто переустановил Windows до последней версии и всё заработало.